# Show source website when sharing a link on Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, url, web, share

I'm a manager of a page on Facebook and now I'm building a site for this page. To be honest I'm way too new to web-developing to be doing such a site, but I would like to try anyway.

My question is, when I see my friend shares a link (from BuzzFeed for example), I would see something like this

---

[image: Link sharing]

---

I believe that to change the thumbnail, the title and the description you would have to edit the meta tag of the html files (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I just want to know how the source website (circled red in the picture) can be displayed through the shared links.

P/S: A side-question, if I want to learn more about building such a "social" site, where can I read more about it and what frameworks should I look into, thanks alot !

Comment: Check out the `og-meta` tags from facebook. There is one for facebook sites

Comment: That is not the “source website”, but the app that was used to publish this. It’s called _app attribution_. It gets shown automatically by Facebook, if the app has relevant platforms configured (normally Website).